# Fix DFP error: "Div div-gpt-ad-XXXXXX is not mapped to a known ad unit."

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-dfp

I set up an ad manager campaign. I clearly followed all the step from DFP, but ads are not showing on the my domain.

The delivery tool of ad manager shows the following error on the same domain where the AdSense ad is running:

> Div div-gpt-ad-XXXXXX is not mapped to a known ad unit

My domain URL is `https://ahilyabaiholkar.in` if anyone could analyze and suggest what is wrong with the code I put from DFP.

[image]

Comment: Can you also include a screen shot of your ad slots, and include the snippet that DFP is asking you to insert into your pages?